# TSQL Allow Match For Right Square Bracket Also From The String

Tags: regex, t-sql

Please note that I want to find special character in string other that what i specify.

```
DECLARE @Temp1 NVARCHAR(100)
SET @Temp1 ='Rajesh[sdf]' 
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z .&()[[,''-]%',@Temp1)
```

After a long finding I got for allowing left square bracket we have to put two times [ i.e [[
But this is not the case for right bracket
The Expression **PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z .&()[[],''-]%',@Temp1)** does not give the proper result expected.

```
DECLARE @Temp1 NVARCHAR(100)
SET @Temp1 ='Rajesh[sdf]' 
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9a-z .&()[[],''-]%',@Temp1)
```

Above code returns patindex 0 as I have removed uppercase . It should return 1 For match for 'R'. So what is right match for right bracket.

Comment: "as I have removed uppercase . It should return 1". That is not correct except for binary collations. In a case insensitive collation `a-z` matches upper case letters too. In a case sensitive collation `a-z` matches all letters except `Z`.

Comment: Also it is not necessary to double up the left square bracket. `SELECT PATINDEX('[[]','[')` returns `1` and if you are to include `-` in the set this needs to be the very first character [for predictable results](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/742841/pattern-syntax-undocumented-difference-in-behaviour-between-varchar-vs-nvarchar). Not sure how to escape `]` at the moment though...

Comment: And some of the individual characters you are searching for have contiguous character codes so you can do 4 range matches and just one loose character left over `PATINDEX( '[0-9A-Z&-),-.[]' ,@Temp1 COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN)` unfortunately `]` doesn't fall within any of the ranges however so that still isn't handled.

Comment: There appears to be no way of escaping a `]` inside a `[]` group using `PATINDEX`. There is a request here [PATINDEX Missing ESCAPE Clause](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/259534/patindex-missing-escape-clause) closed as won't fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this link](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/79113-patindex-character), it looks like `[[` is not the escape for `[` but rather `[[]`. In other words, a left square bracket *within* a left-right square bracket pair.

This being the case, your `PATINDEX` should be as follows.

```
PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z .&()[[]],''-]%',@Temp1)
```

Notice the additional `]` since the first `]` closes out the `[]` pair to match `[`.

**EDIT #1:**

What if you were to try something like this? What we're doing is first replacing the bothersome `[]` characters with `()` and then doing your search for special characters not in your list.

```
DECLARE @Temp1 NVARCHAR(100)
SET @Temp1 ='Rajesh[sdf]'
SET @Temp1 = REPLACE(@Temp1,'[','(')
SET @Temp1 = REPLACE(@Temp1,']',')')
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z .&(),''-]%',@Temp1)
```

Unfortunately, I can't test this at this time because I don't have a working copy of SQL Server right this second. I will try to test in a bit once I get one installed.

**EDIT #2:**

Now that I've been able to test, I've confirmed this as a possible solution.

```
DECLARE @Temp1 NVARCHAR(100)
SET @Temp1 ='Rajesh[sdf]+'
SET @Temp1 = REPLACE(@Temp1,'[','.')
SET @Temp1 = REPLACE(@Temp1,']','.')
SET @Temp1 = REPLACE(@Temp1,'-','.')
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9a-z .&(),'']%',@Temp1 COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)
```

There were several challenges that needed to be overcome.

- The code page for my database was *case-insensitive* (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_**CI**_AS). I needed to use `COLLATE` to get around this. Note that I used the `BIN` collation because even the `CS` collation didn't behave as expected. This fixed the problem where removing `A-Z` still wouldn't match on `R`.
- The `-` character from the original `PATINDEX` expression was not working correctly. This is probably because it is a special character in the expression (i.e. "through" in `a-z`). I tried escaping it like `--` and while this worked, my additional test case of a `+` was broken. I found this really odd, but in the end decided it might be easier to just substitute `-` with another character I knew I was going to reject (`.`).
- The string `REPLACE` functions reduces the complexity of the `PATINDEX` (and makes it actually work) by removing the offending special characters from the expression completely. Assuming you'll always have at least one character you're rejecting in the `PATINDEX`, using these `REPLACE` expressions should be a workable solution. In theory it will slow things down a bit, but that's something that will just have to be tested in real-life to see if it matters any.

I know that this solution works as I've been able to test it. Just needed a little bit of time to get SQL Server Express Edition up and running!

Comment: The result for SET @Temp1 ='Rajesh[sdf]' 
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9a-z .&()[[]],''-]%',@Temp1) does not match R as i have removed A-Z.

Comment: I guess I'm confused. Are you wanting to match the `R` or the `]`? If you remove uppercase characters from your character class (`A-Z`) then it shouldn't match `R`. It seems to be working as expected in that case. Does it match `]`?

Comment: Now I see the `^`...I understand what you want now. Sorry for my misunderstanding. I'm trying to reproduce the problem but am not having any luck yet.

Comment: SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z .&(),''-]%','Jaiprakash Hydro-Power Ltd. [Erstwhile]') RETURNS 29
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z .&(),[[''-]%','Jaiprakash Hydro-Power Ltd. [Erstwhile]') RETURNS 39 i.e FOR SQUARE bracket position
But SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z .&(),]]''-]%','Jaiprakash Hydro-Power Ltd. [Erstwhile]') OR SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z .&(),[]]''-]%','Jaiprakash Hydro-Power Ltd. [Erstwhile]')
doesnot RETURN LEFT SQUARE bracket position.

Comment: I suspect this is due to the interpreter losing track of the character class by including the extra `]`. Unfortunately, I'm at a loss for a working copy of SQL Server with which I can test...

Comment: Please see my updated response (Edit #2). I've been able to test and come up with a working solution. I know the additional `REPLACE` statements might not be desired, but they do make the `PATINDEX` much more workable. By removing the `[` or `]` `REPLACE` statements, the additional test cases shown in these comments pass as well.

Comment: BTW: You can use http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ iif you just want to quickly test something on SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, MySQL...

Comment: @MartinSmith: thanks for that! I had done some looking for something like that but couldn't find anything, so I resorted to setting up a new instance.

Comment: I've been trying to do it with REGEX and PATINDEX but this solution is much simpler! Thank you so much! I change de [] for (), change my value, then change it back to [].